# How to read the value returned by a powershell script with ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

I am trying the following Powershell script:

```bsh
Function jello-code {
    return "jello"
}

jello-code
```

In Ansible playbook I have a task defined as

```yaml
- name : run jello script.
  win_shell: C:Projects\scripts\jello.ps1
  args:
    chdir:  C:Projects\scripts
  register : script_return
- debug : msg = {{script_return.stdout}}
```

Currently the value shown by debug task is

```
ok: [clientmachine.com] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

I always get the same *"Hello world!"* message.

My goal is to do other tasks based on the value returned by the Powershell script.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? "How to read the value returned by a powershell script with ansible" You already do it: `{{script_return.stdout}}`. Are you wondering why you get "Hello World" instead of "jello"? Or are you looking for conditional tasks?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for the ambiguity. I was asking why "Hello World" is returned instead of "jello".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this happens because, the default message of the `debug` module is `Hello world!` you can refer to the documentation default of the [parameter `msg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#parameter-msg).

And because your YAML syntax is bogus, then your `debug` task prints its default.

A good recommendation would be to avoid mixing the YAML syntax and the older `key=value` one.
A working example of this would be:

```yaml
- name: run jello script.
  win_shell: C:Projects\scripts\jello.ps1
  args:
    chdir:  C:Projects\scripts
  register: script_return
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ script_return.stdout }}"
```

If you insist on having the other syntax — named `key=value` — though, note that your issue is coming from the space that you put around your equal sign.

Here are the different behaviours with and without spaces:

- ```yaml
  - debug: msg={{script_return.stdout}}
  ```

  is correct and prints

  ```
  "msg": "jello"
  ```
- ```yaml
  - debug: msg = {{script_return.stdout}}
  ```

  is bogus and prints

  ```
  "msg": "Hello world!"
  ```
- ```yaml
  - debug: msg ={{script_return.stdout}}
  ```

  is bogus and prints

  ```
  "msg": "Hello world!"
  ```
- ```yaml
  - debug: msg= {{script_return.stdout}}
  ```

  is bogus and prints

  ```
  "msg": ""
  ```

So, in short, in this syntax, do not add spaces around the equal sign.