# Copy one file between remote hosts with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have 2 remote servers (Prod and Demo) and I would like to copy the latest file from a particular folder in Prod to another folder in Demo. Only one file is to be copied.

I can find the latest file in Prod using:

```
- name: Get files in folder
  find:
    paths: "/path_in_prod/arch/"
  register: found_files
  become: true
  become_user: root
  delegate_to: "{{ prod_server }}"
  when: copy_content_from_prod is defined

- name: Get latest file
  set_fact:
    latest_file: "{{ found_files.files | sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=true) | first }}"
  become: true
  become_user: root
  delegate_to: "{{ prod_server }}"
  when: copy_content_from_prod is defined
```

I can check I have the correct file (debug).

When I try to copy the file with

```
- name: Fetch the file from prod
  fetch: src= {{ latest_file.path }} dest=buffer/ flat=yes
  delegate_to: "{{ prod_server }}"

- name: Copy the file to demo
  copy: src=buffer/{{ latest_file.path | basename }} dest=/path_in_demo/in
```

I get a "File not found" error. But if I look for the file it is there (latest_file.path on Prod).

this is the error message

```
fatal: [demoServerHost -> ProdServerHost ]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "file not found: "}
```

I do not know if I am interpreting the error message correctly but it seems to be looking in Demo in order to copy onto Prod?

Comment: Your syntax is buggy, when using `k=v` you absolutely need no spaces between the equal and the key or value. Also worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62859546/2123530

Comment: Also mind that delegating a fact to an host without having `delegate_facts: yes` is pointless: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-facts

Comment: Last but not least, when you `delegate_to` a unique host, you might also want to use [`run_once: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once), so you don't run the thing multiple times on the same host.

Comment: the extra space was the problem! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue, where the copy task hangs indefinitely. Here is my example which is not site specific (will identify the site and user using the options).
The easiest solution I have found is to scp directly using the shell module:

```
-   name: scp files onto '{{ target_destination }}' looping for each file on '{{ target_source }}'
    shell: 'scp {{ hostvars[target_source].ansible_user }}@{{ hostvars[target_source].ansible_host }}:/opt/{{ hostvars[target_source].ansible_user }}/{{ item }} /opt/{{ destuser.stdout }}'
    loop: '{{ diffout.stdout_lines }}'
    when: diffout.stdout != ""
```

Some notes:

- "target_source" and "target_destination" are defined using the extra-vars option
- diffout is an earlier task comparing the folders on "Prod" and "Demo" and shows any new files to copy
- this task is run on the "target_destination" (in my case Prod)
- hostvars[target_source] will look at the variables for the "target_source" host in the inventory
- this serves as a "pull" from Demo to Prod in my case, if your "Demo" doesn't have permissions, then you could delegate the task to "Prod" and rearrange the scp to look for "Demo" vars to push from "Prod"